# multiple conditions in $match in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, match, aggregate

I have a collection AccountSupport. I has array of supports property. I want to filter the record on parent property and a property of an array

```
db = {
  "AccountSupport": [
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9c6170b38c373530c5b00a"),
    "accountName" : "domestic",
    "supports" : [ 
        {
            "subject" : "Traverse",
            "desc" : "Travers support consolidation",
        }, 
        {
            "subject" : "Non Traverse",
            "desc" : "Non Travers support consolidation",
        },
        {
            "subject" : "Domestic Traverse",
            "desc" : "Domestic Travers support consolidation",
        }       
    ],

  }
```

I want to filter on accountName and supports.subject.

**Below is my query**

```
db.AccountSupport.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "supports.subject": "Traverse"
        },
        {
          "accountName": "domestic"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$supports"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "SupportName": "$supports.subject",
      "desc": "$supports.desc"
    }
  }
])
```

The above query returns me all the supports of a particular accountName whereas i only want the single object of the matched subject.  Is above the simplest approach to do it?

**MongoPlayGround**

[MongoPlayGround for my query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mQVFStpnoem)

Comment: In regards to your comment about Lean(), are you using an ORM such as Mongoose?

Comment: @james yes im using mongoose

Comment: So in your js code, could you not just get the first element [0] to remove the square brackets and then get the first element of "subject" to return { accountName: 'domestic' { "SupportName": "Traverse", "desc": "Travers support consolidation" } }

Comment: yes, i have done like that only, also but the query which i posted in the answer does it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the query to get my needed result, not sure if this is the best practice though, as the other answers posted works fine as well for the mentioned requirement

```
db.AccountSupport.find({'accountName': 'domestic' },
                      { 
                         'supports': 
                                { 
                                  '$elemMatch': { 'subject': 'Traverse'}
                                }
                       })
```

Answer (score 2):

Took a little bit of experimenting but try this:

```
db.AccountSupport.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "accountName": "domestic",
      "supports.subject": "Traverse"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      accountName: "$accountName",
      subject: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$supports",
          as: "supports",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$supports.subject",
              "Traverse"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {
    "accountName": "domestic",
    "subject": [
      {
        "desc": "Travers support consolidation",
        "subject": "Traverse"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just add another `$match` step to your aggregation query. Since the `$unwind` breaks your doc into 3 docs, you can then match the individual doc you are interested in returning. The `$filter` solution by james looks worth investigating and could be the simpler approach for you.

Query:

```
db.AccountSupport.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "supports.subject": "Traverse"
        },
        {
          "accountName": "domestic"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$supports"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "supports.subject": "Traverse"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "SupportName": "$supports.subject",
      "desc": "$supports.desc"
    }
  }
])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "SupportName": "Traverse",
    "_id": ObjectId("5e9c6170b38c373530c5b00a"),
    "desc": "Travers support consolidation"
  }
]
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4uo2J8gToaz)

Comment: A good answer! You can add _id: 0 as a final parameter in the $project field to remove the ID from the response - and then I think your answer now trumps mine :) https://mongoplayground.net/p/N_AQwn98TPO

Comment: @james - I left the _id in there since the OP didn't mention anything about including or excluding it. Not sure which is really cleaner/better - using $filter in the $project or doing an $unwind and  $match - nice that there are multiple options that are successful to choose from.

Comment: That is true! not sure why I had that in my head. But yes multiple solutions is always good.

Comment: Anything that can be done to avoid `$unwind` should be done.  james's answer is The Best Practice for this use case:   Use a dotpath to the item in the array to yield T or F if at least 1 match occurs in the array, then `$filter` to keep ONLY the target items.

Comment: @james 
 i'm also trying to get the accountName in the response, like below
{ 
accountName: 'domestic'
 {
    "SupportName": "Traverse",
    "desc": "Travers support consolidation"
  }
}

also im trying to get the response as plain object and not mongooseCoreArray to which i tried to use LEAN() but it doesn't work.

Comment: $project: {
        accountName:  "$accountName",
i have added the above property in the query and i gets the accountName